# Circular-linear regression with covariates in R

Tags: r, regression

I have data showing when an animal came to a survey station. [example csv file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/243e6osg8o7187a/StackOverflowExampleData.csv) The first few lines of data look like this:

```
Site_ID   DateTime            HourOfDay MinTemp LunarPhase       Habitat
F1        6/12/2013 14:01:00  14             -1       0           river
F1        6/12/2013 14:23:00  14             -1       0           river
F2        6/13/2013 1:21:00   1               3       1           upland
F2        6/14/2013 1:33:00   1               4       2           upland
F3        6/14/2013 1:48:00   1               4       2           river
F3        6/15/2013 11:08:00  11              0       0           river
```

I would like to perform a circular-linear regression in R to determine peak activity times. The dependent variable could be DateTime or HourOfDay, whichever is easier. I would like to incorporate the covariates Site_ID (random effect), plus MinTemp, LunarPhase, and Habitat into a mixed-effects model.

I have tried using the lm.circular function of program circular, and have the following code:

```
data<-read.csv("StackOverflowExampleData.csv")
data$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(as.character(data$DateTime), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
data$LunarPhase<-as.factor(data$LunarPhase)
str(data)

library(circular)

y<-data$DateTime
y<-circular(y, units ="hours",template = "clock24",rotation = "clock")
x<-data[,c(1,4,5,6)]
lm.circular(y=y, x=x, init=c(1,1,1,1), type='c-l', verbose=TRUE)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in Ops.POSIXt(x, 12) : '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

Apparently this is a known bug, but I was confused by [this threat about it](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/859) and could not determine an appropriate work-around. Suggestions?

Also, my ultimate goal with this data was to run a circular-linear version of a glm, and then test several models against one another using AIC or some other information theoretics method. The model I'm seeking would be a circular-linear version of something like this:

```
glmer(HourOfDay~MinTemp+LunarPhase+Habitat+(1|Site_ID),family=binomial,data=data)
```

Perhaps this is an inappropriate application of the circular package. If so, I'm open to other suggestions of models and/or graphics that would investigate peak activity using the data and covariates.

Note: I did search for related discussions and found [this somewhat relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249329/fitting-a-circular-regression), but it was never answered, did not request a solution in R, and was of a different scope.

Comment: especially if you want to add a random effect term to this model, I think you'll have to use something like [AD Model Builder](http://admb-project.org), possibly via the R2admb package ...

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem is caused by `conversion.circular`. There, a `POSIXlt` object is divided by 12. This is an operation that has a non-defined outcome:

```
> as.POSIXlt('2005-07-16') / 2
Error in Ops.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt("2005-07-16"), 2) : 
  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

So, it seems that you cannot use data of this class as input for the `circular` package. I could not find any mention of `POSIXlt` data in the examples. Maybe you need to specify the timestamps simply as a number, not as a `POSIXlt` object.